vcpkg dependency is not propagated through ProjectReference
I have a Visual Studio C++ solution with several projects. For simplicity, let's say that one is a static library (LibA) and another one is a console application (AppB). AppB depends on LibA and this is expressed as a "project reference" (AppB.vcxproj has <ProjectReference Include="..\LibA.vcxproj">).
Now, LibA depends on a third-party library (LibX) which is added via vcpkg and has a type from that library mentioned in its header.
That means that AppB not only indirectly depends on LibX but also needs this library present even just to include LibA's header.
I would have expected it to "just work" (e.g. ProjectReference transitively add LibX with LibA), but it didn't.
What is the correct approach here? Do I have to always list all transitive dependencies if I ever use Project References?

List all dependencies in your C++ project including transitive dependencies. The C++ project support is essentially a heavily modified fork of the legacy style project support for .NET Framework. The newer SDK style project support (.NET project SDKs) supports transitive dependencies with ProjectReference. Legacy does not support transitive dependencies and SDK style projects don't support C++.
